# Hot to make jackson to use snake_case / camelCase on demand in a Spring Boot REST API?

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-boot, jackson

I want to support both snake_case and camelCase in the json interface of my rest API.

Jackson uses camelCase by default. I know there are many ways of making Jackson to use snake_case:

Annotating properties individually: `@JsonProperty("first_name")`

Annotating classes with: `@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)`

Applying it to the whole application inside application.properties:
`spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=SNAKE_CASE`

But I haven't found information about how to allow the consumer to request the desired case. For example by using content negotiation (Accepts, Content-Type headers)

Lets suppose we have the following example:

```
@RequestMapping("/my-resource") 
public interface ApiController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = {"application/json"})
    MyResource createResource(@RequestBody MyResource myResource);

    @GetMapping(value="/{resourceId}", produces = {"application/json"})
    MyResource readResource(@PathVariable String resourceId);
}
```

So one use case could be to use custom json media-type and provide content negotiation headers like:

`Accepts: application/vnd.snake+json`

and let the default `application/json` to use camelCase.

But I cannot find the way of making jackson to use two different Mapper configurations based on the content negotiation.

Comment: Wanting to support two formats seems like a worthy objective, but in practice you're doubling the surface area of your api (and the requisite testing required). You will need to create two different `Mapper`(s)  and potentially try both. And (potentially) both mappings might be valid. From [Mapper Features](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Mapper-Features), *Jackson defines a set of per-mapper configuration, which can ONLY be defined before using ObjectMapper -- meaning that these settings can not be changed on-the-fly, on per-request basis.*

Answer (score 2):

Good question, I would suggest to take a look into [content negotiation](https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc) and [http message converter](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-httpmessageconverter-rest) topics.

It seems you can configure two instances of `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`
to produce *application/vnd.snake+json* or *application/json*. 
Set it with specific media type and differently configured *ObjectMapper*

Code modification can looks like:

```
MyMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter extends MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter
{
  public MyMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(ObjectMapper objectMapper, MediaType mediaType)
  {
     super(objectMapper, mediaType);
  }
}
```

Configuration can looks like:

```java
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void configureMessageConverters(
    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {     
      converters.add(new MyMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(snake, new MediaType("application", "vnd.snake+json")));
      converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(camel, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
      super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

As per new version of spring boot, I end up doing this way -

```
    @Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterSnakeCase = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterSnakeCase.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(new MediaType("application", "vnd.snake+json")));
    mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterSnakeCase.setObjectMapper(objectMapperSnakeCase());

    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterCamelCase = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterCamelCase.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterCamelCase.setObjectMapper(objectMapperSnakeCase());

    converters.add(mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterCamelCase);
    converters.add(mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterSnakeCase);
    WebMvcConfigurer.super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
}
```